# SELinux restrict Apache/PHP access

Tags: php, hardening, selinux

I installed a minimal CentOS system with Apache, PHP and SELinux in a default configuration:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      29
```

If I want to change the Apache root directory, I must relabel this new directory otherwise SELinux block the access. But I found, with PHP scripts, that it's possible to do a lot more than I expected. For example, I can do the following actions without any alerts:

- read `/etc/passwd`,
- list `/var/tmp`,
- display kernel version,
- establish connection with external hosts

However I receive AVC alerts when I try to read attributes of `/etc/shadow` or when I try to access home directory.

First of all, is it normal? And how can I tweak SELinux to restrict more PHP actions?

I use CentOS 7 and my selinux-policy version is 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7.
(I also tried the same with Fedora and get the same results)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone needs to be able to read `/etc/passwd` and write to `/var/tmp`. So these are not an issue.

The kernel version is not really an issue either, provided you're actually installing updates, using Ksplice, etc.

As for making outbound network connections, you can restrict this, as some web sites do not need to make such connections. But sometimes they do, for instance most web sites will need to connect to a database. You can manage this with SELinux booleans, such as:

```
# semanage boolean -l | grep httpd_can_network
httpd_can_network_relay        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network relay
httpd_can_network_connect_db   (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect db
httpd_can_network_connect      (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect
httpd_can_network_memcache     (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network memcache
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can network connect cobbler
```

Setting `httpd_can_network_connect` allows all outbound network connections to anywhere; the others are more restrictive and only allow connecting to each specific service.

---

Also remember that if you are using nginx and php-fpm, that php is not restricted by SELinux until CentOS 6.6 and 7.

Comment: Very nice answer. One thing I would add is that SELinux cannot do some of the stuff that the OP is asking but in order to achieve that the OP might want to use SElinux in combination with Linux Containers (in whatever form).

Comment: Even with [httpd_can_network_connect] boolean set as false (as all other httpd_can_network*), PHP is still able to connect outside.

Comment: @jbrsn You forgot to post your CentOS version, and you should look at your version of `selinux-policy` package too.

Comment: I use CentOS 7 and my `selinux-policy` version is 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7

Answer (score 0):

You need block system command in php?
Check php directive

```
disable_functions =
```

This?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view `/etc/passwd` need to be readable from every users of the system.

Your php script run with apache user, so it's normal the script can read `/etc/passwd`

In apache virtualhost I use `"php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/example.com"` you can do the same thing for `upload_tmp_dir` and `session.save_path`